# Asyncsocket crashes

Tags: ios, xcode, asyncsocket

Can anyone tell me why the code connects

```
- (IBAction)connectBtn:(id)sender {

  socket = [[AsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate: self];
  [socket connectToHost: @"127.0.0.1" onPort: 4321 error: nil];

}
```

and the code below crashes on connecttohost

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 socket = [[AsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate: self];
  [super viewDidLoad];

}
- (IBAction)connectBtn:(id)sender {

[socket connectToHost: @"127.0.0.1" onPort: 4321 error: nil];

 }
```

the socket is defined in view controller.h file

```
 @interface ViewController : UIViewController{
 AsyncSocket *socket;

 }
```

Comment: Can you post the error you get? Is socket weakly retained if so it is probably getting deallocated.

Comment: Also (actually doesn't know if there's something related to the error), but always call `[super viewDidLoad]` as the first line inside the method

Comment: The error is below,  can you explain weakly retained  I tried

Comment: 2013-10-13 20:09:53.304 test005[8629:11303] -[__NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7147f50
2013-10-13 20:09:53.306 test005[8629:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7147f50'
*** First throw call stack:
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)